# Luminoth requires a TensorFlow >= 1.5 installation

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection

while executing the query

`lumi dataset transform --type csv --data-dir data/ --output-dir tfdata/ --split train --split val --only-classes=table`

I get this message:

`Luminoth requires a TensorFlow >= 1.5 installation.
Depending on your use case, you should install either tensorflow or
tensorflow-gpu packages manually or via PyPI.`

even though i have installed

[image]

Comment: Does importing tensorflow work in a python interpreter?

Comment: @NaReSh LaLiT did you manage to get it resolved ?

Comment: Did you install CUDA, cuDNN drivers? See https://luminoth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/installation.html